# Increment numbers in list from a certain point

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list of numbers, e.g. `[50,100,150,200,250]`. I need to increment (or decrement) each number from a specified index and by a specified amount. I have been able to do this in two ways:

```
from itertools import islice

l = [50,100,150,200,250]
start_increment_index = 3

l[start_increment_index:] = [e+100 for e in l[start_increment_index:]]
print (l)

l = [50,100,150,200,250]

l[start_increment_index:] = [e+100 for e in islice(l,start_increment_index,len(l))]
print (l)
```

Both print: `[50, 100, 150, 300, 350]`.

However, my real list contains millions of numbers and this operation is performed repeatedly with different indexes and different increments/decrements. Would there be a faster way of doing this using a Python list? I have been considering writing my own C/C++ extension to deal with this.

Edit: Would this be a useful module for Python in general? Having a function written in C which can take parameters `(python_list_object, increment_amount, start_index, end_index)`?

Comment: If asking a Python question, don't add unrelated language tags (like for C or C++). If you *do* write a C or C++ module, *then* you can use the (relevant) tag for questions about it.

Comment: Check Python's array structure, it is efficient array of numeric values

Comment: If you need the best performance, you should write a C/C++ program (the algorithm is simple to write, and maybe a little thread-optimisable). Otherwise, if your goal is to get this one job done, just stick with this script and wait for answers; generally speaking, it depends on how big are the numbers (like millions or trillions), and wether how many times you think you're going to be using this script/programs.

Comment: If you are accessing the lists only sparingly, you could store the increments in a binary search tree (`TreeSet` in Java, not sure what's the Python equivalent). This way, you can get the initial value for some index from your list, and all the increments before that index from the tree, and calculate the number on demand.

Comment: Ok thank you for your comments, sorry about the tags

Comment: Before trying to write C extension, you should try to run your code with the [pypy](https://pypy.org/) interpreter. It can be an easy way to improve speed. However it may not work especially if your code already depends on some C extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem in your solution that you creates(allocating memory + copy) two lists. First it's list comprehension by itself and second `l[start_increment_index:]` inside it.

If you data source is python list, you can do you operation for O(n):

```
for i in range(start_increment_index, len(l)):
    l[i] += increment
```

NB: define `increment` first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends specifically on your goals. I suppose that you can use segment tree for this case. For more information see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree.

Just for brief description. This structure represents array upon which will be performed range operations (like addition/substraction subarray with number) This structure is optimized for case where you have very big number of such range queries.

Note: if you want to use only python list structure, then you can implement sparse table (it is another view of segment tree with implicit storing of tree in arrays)